# DNN Skin not apply to some forum controls

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have create new skin for DNN forums module and assign it to forums page created from admin menu.
Assigned skin apply to initial thread listing controls but not apply to postEdit and forum settings page.

Any expert can help me out for this issue?

Your suggestions are always welcome.

Thanks
Amit Shah

Answer (score 0):

The forums module, when editing or replying to a post uses the Admin/Edit skin also defined on the site settings page.

Try configuring your skin as the Admin/Edit skin (in older versions of DNN it is called Admin, in newer, it is Edit)